# Bitmap not loading in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I am unable to load the bitmap image in the PictureBox. It gives me an error saying the parameter is not valid.

```
        Image up = Image.FromFile("somePath");
        Image down = Image.FromFile("anotherPath");

        using (down)
        {
            using(var bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000))
            {
                using(var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    canvas.DrawImage(up, 0, 0);
                    canvas.DrawImage(down, 0, 500);
                    canvas.Save();
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;// this line gives the error
                } 
            }
        }
```

The size of my pictureBox is also 1000X1000. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

EDIT 1:
Error Description:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()    at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode
>   mode)    at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs
>   e, Int16 layer)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Add error description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove using statements on `bmp`. Because, your bitmap is disposed after `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` and you get an error on paint event.

```
Image up = Image.FromFile("somePath");
Image down = Image.FromFile("anotherPath");

using (down)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
    using(var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        canvas.DrawImage(up, 0, 0);
        canvas.DrawImage(down, 0, 500);
        canvas.Save();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;// this line gives the error
    } 
 }
```

Comment: @JustCurious glad to help